# append to empty dataframe iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a for loop. At each iteration a dataframe is created. I want this dataframe to be appended to an overall result dataframe.

Currently I tried to do it with this code:

```
resultDf = pd.DataFrame()
for name in list:
    iterationresult = calculatesomething(name)
    resultDf.append(iterationresult)
print(resultDf)
```

However, the `resultDf` is empty.

How can this be done?

**UPDATE**

I think changing

```
resultDf.append(iterationresult)
```

to

```
resultDf = resultDf.append(iterationresult)
```

does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Not iterative, but how about simply:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([calculatesomething(name) for name in list])
```

This is much more straightforward, and faster as well.

Another idiomatic idea could be to do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns = ["name"])
df["calc"] = df.name.map(calculatesomething)
```

By the way, it's a bad practice to call a `list` `list`, because it will shadow the builtin type.